# Joomla custom module $params stays empty

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-module

When I call my custom module from the index.php of my template, the $params variable in the modules.php, with my module settings from the backend, stays empty. So I cannot access the module parameters. Here is the module activation of my index.php:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_custom_module','CustomModule');
$attribs['layout'] = 'startpage';
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, $attribs);
```

The module gets loaded, but I cannot access my parameters from the backend settings. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

To get an object for the parameters of a module, you will need to use `JRegistry`. Have a look at the following example based on your code:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_custom_module','CustomModule');
$attribs['layout'] = 'startpage';
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, $attribs);

// Get params and output
$params = new JRegistry($module->params);  
echo $param['param_name'];
```

You will of course need to change `param_name` to the name of your parameter.

Hope this helps

Comment: I added also your suggestion with JRegistry, but $params (to be more concrete, the data object of $params where the params are stored) remains empty. The module will be also loaded on a different page where the module will be loaded because of the Joomla module menue settings, here are the parameters available.

Comment: @Perino - I don't know why this isn't working for you as I've tested this just 5 minutes ago with the login module and it worked perfectly. To debug the issue, add `var_dump($module);` and see what gets displayed. You should see a dump of data and within that, there should be some parameter information. Let me know what you see. The after that, add `var_dump($params);` and you should see only the parameter information.

Comment: object(stdClass)[864]
  public 'id' => int 0
  public 'title' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'module' => string 'mod_custom_module' (length=17)
  public 'position' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'content' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'showtitle' => int 0
  public 'control' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'params' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: It appears your parameters have not registered properly. Open the module in the Joomla Backend, and click the save button, then try again

Comment: Yes, I did, but still remains empty. It seems the parameters stays empty when the module is manually loaded by the view (in this case the index.php). When the module will be loaded automatically on pages, which are defined in the menu section of the module backend settings, then the $parameters gets loaded right?!

Comment: This shouldn't happen as it works perfectly fine for the login module for me. I rendered it in the footer of the default Protostar template and was able to output all the parameters. Maybe someone else might be able to shed some light on the matter

Comment: AddOn:Same problem when the module will be called from a normal view/layout

Comment: I don't think the layout type is the issue

Comment: Same result with Login module when I do var_dump($module) in mod_login.php: object(stdClass)[806]
  public 'id' => int 0
  public 'title' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'module' => string 'mod_login' (length=9)
  public 'position' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'content' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'showtitle' => int 0
  public 'control' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'params' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: Ok that is very odd. What exact version of Joomla are you using? 3.3.6?

Comment: Yes it is very odd! Joomla Version 3.3.6. I do not have a clue. Maybe you could have also a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353636/joomla-access-state-variable-in-modules